# select for specific datetime past hourly data in a range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to obtain for a specific datetime past hourly data in a custom range. For example, the following code retrieve data for datetime - [1,2,3,24,168,169,170]

```
`With DataCte(Data,Consum) as (
select dateadd(hh,datepart(hh,Data), cast(CAST(Data as date) as datetime)) 
Data, AVG(Consum) Consum
from Grafic_SEN  group by dateadd(hh,datepart(hh,Data), 
cast(CAST(Data as date) as datetime)) 
)
select  t1.Data,t2.Consum,t3.Consum,t4.Consum,t5.Consum,
t6.Consum,t7.Consum,t8.Consum
from DataCte t1 
left join DataCte t2 on t2.Data=DATEADD(hh,-1,t1.Data) 
left join DataCte t3 on t3.Data=DATEADD(hh,-2,t1.Data) 
left join DataCte t4 on t4.Data=DATEADD(hh,-3,t1.Data) 
left join DataCte t5 on t5.Data=DATEADD(hh,-24,t1.Data)
left join DataCte t6 on t6.Data=DATEADD(hh,-168,t1.Data)
left join DataCte t7 on t7.Data=DATEADD(hh,-169,t1.Data)
left join DataCte t8 on t8.Data=DATEADD(hh,-170,t1.Data)
where cast(t1.Data as date)='2015.01.01' order by t1.Data`
```

The problem is that my code is very slow.
Thank you for your help.

Edit: My data starts from date "2014.01.01 00:00" and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqFAF.png) is presented
results obtained from my code.

Comment: What datatype is Data and Consum?

Comment: not clear.thorw sample data and desire output.

Comment: Data is datetime and Consum is float type. Result must be the "Consum" column shifted by -1, -2... hours in the past